# Searching for the upper bound in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, upperbound

I'm trying to get the *index* of the nearest upper bound (unless equivalent value found) in the array `size` using the value in variable `sum` as upper bound, and then find the value at the same index in the array `value`.

For example: if the value in `sum` is 270, my program should find the value 280 located at index 6 in `size` and output the value at corresponding `value[6]`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double x = 0;
    double y = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    double size[27] = {24, 28, 32, 38, 48, 240, 280, 320, 360, 380,
                       420, 480, 560, 600, 640, 700, 720, 800, 840,
                       960, 980, 1120, 1200, 1280, 1440, 1680, 1920};

    double value[27] = {.0022, .0026, .0029, .0035, .0044, .0219,
                        .0256, .0292, .0328, .0384, .0438, .0513,
                        .0547, .0584, .0641,.0656, .073, .0766,
                        .0875, .0877, .0897, .1023, .1094, .1169,
                        .1313, .1531, .175};

    cout << "Enter width: " << endl;
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Enter height: " << endl;
    cin >> y;

    x = ceil(x) + 3;
    y = ceil(y) + 3;

    sum = x * y;
}
```

Comment: If only there were a function with a name like [`std::upper_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound)... Also what's with the `value` array? Why are you trying to initialise it with `double`s and then copying those values (which are now all `0`) to `size`?

Comment: Any reason you use `memcpy` instead of `std::copy`?

Comment: Step through your `size` array until you find the point where `size[i] < sum` and `size[i+1] > sum`. Then determine the nearest value out of those two points - perhaps by calculating the absolute value of `size[i] - sum`. Take into account that `sum` can equal `size[i]`.

Comment: once I use the upper_bound function, how do i know which array location that is in?

Comment: The advice would be to read a proper book first.

Comment: These are doubles, not ints: `.0022, .0026, .0029, .0035`

Comment: @user3867859 I have no idea what you mean, `upper_bound` returns an iterator to the first value greater than the requested value.

Comment: The array size is sorted?

Comment: @Naseef yes its sorted.

Comment: And what should be the behavior if the entry in `size` is equal?

Comment: @JamesKanze If its equal, it uses that position in array(size) and find the same index value to array(value)

Comment: @user3867859 Which means that you probably want `std::lower_bound`, rather than `std::upper_bound` (but both can be used).

Comment: @JamesKanze if there is no exact value found, it has to find the upper bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this -

```
    double x = 0;
    double y = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    int size[27] = {24, 28, 32, 38, 48, 240, 280, 320, 360, 380,
    420, 480, 560, 600, 640, 700, 720, 800, 840, 960, 980, 1120, 1200, 1280, 1440, 1680, 1920};
    double value[27] = {.0022, .0026, .0029, .0035, .0044, .0219,
    .0256, .0292, .0328, .0384, .0438, .0513, .0547, .0584, .0641,.0656, .073, .0766, .0875, .0877, .0897, .1023, .1094, .1169, .1313, .1531, .175};

    cout << "Enter width: " << endl;
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Enter height: " << endl;
    cin >> y;

    x = ceil(x) + 3;
    y = ceil(y) + 3;

    sum = x * y;

    for (int i=0;i<27;i++)
    {
        if (size[i]>=sum)
        {
          cout<<value[i]<<endl; 
          break;
        }
        else if(i==26)
        {
            cout<<"No upper Bound find\n";
        }
    }
```

There are other ways to solve this. But as you said you are a beginner. I have given the simple bruteforce solution. :)

Comment: If I use x = 15.4 , y = 16, sum = 19*19 = 361. On array size, 380 is the closest value, which puts it at size[10], and value[10] = .0384 while this program outputs .0328?

Comment: However, thanks for the code. I will take a closer look and see how I can fix it to solve it.

Comment: @user3867859 Check it now. It has been fixed.

Comment: what does "[pos]" refer to?

Comment: it has no use. I have deleted that. Check again please.

Comment: Does the issue is fixed?

Answer (score 1):

To get the index of the upper bound simply use [`std::upper_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) like this (requires that the range is at least partially sorted):

```
// Get iterator to upper bound.
auto it = std::upper_bound(std::begin(size), std::end(size), sum);

// Get index by iterator subtraction.
std::size_t index = it - std::begin(size);
```

Then use `index` e.g. as:

```
std::cout << value[index] << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to get the index of the upper bound by this:

```
upper_bound(size, size+27, sum) - size
```

Get the value of upper bound:

```
int index = upper_bound(size, size+27, sum) - size;
cout << size[index] << endl;
```

I tested performance using the code below. Each one-line code under a for loop give the index where upper bound is.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    unsigned char Array[8] = {5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40};
    unsigned char* it = upper_bound(Array, Array+8, 23);
    for(int i = 0 ;i < 100000000; ++i)//0.46s
        distance(Array, it);
    for(int i = 0 ;i < 100000000; ++i)//0.21s
        it - begin(Array);
    for(int i = 0 ;i < 100000000; ++i)//0.19s
        it - Array;
}
```

In my test, the last one is the fastest.

Comment: very clean! Could you explain a bit more how the operator works? Are the iterators actually int and their values in sequence?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way can be done in 2 lines:

```
auto size_ub = std::upper_bound(std::begin(size), std::end(size), sum);
int idx = std::distance(std::begin(size), size_ub);

cout << value[idx] << endl;
```

Please note that `size` must be partitioned with respect to sum. A sorted array as in your example meets this criteria.